# json how to make the result to alter as expected value

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have an ajax using jquery and the ajax response is a json. My ajax as follows:

```
$.post("updatechatusers.php", {courseid:cid}, function (data) {
         console.log(data);

            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(json).each(function(i,val){
            $.each(val,function(k,v){
            console.log(k+" : "+ v);       
            });
            });


     },"json");
```

But I am getting my console as follows:

```
 [Object, Object, Object, Object]

id:1 name:test1 .....
```

My `json` is as follows:

```
var j ='[{"id":"1","name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test2"},{"id":"3","name":"test3"},{"id":"4","name":"test4"},{"id":"5","name":"test5"}]';
```

I got output as id:1 name:test1 .....

I do not want id: name: , What I need is `1 test1.......` Without using the labels of json.

Comment: your code is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zsLk691z/). try reproducing the issue so that we can fix

Comment: @JSantosh I am getting as id : 1 name : test1. I do not want id: name: . I ant 1 test1

Comment: can you post what you are expecting. In OP you said you got an error.

Comment: @J Santosh updated please take a look!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need comma separated data like this `1-test1,2-test2,3-test3,4-test4,5-test5,`

Code is

```js
var j = '[{"id":"1","name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test2"},{"id":"3","name":"test3"},{"id":"4","name":"test4"},{"id":"5","name":"test5"}]';
console.log(JSON.parse(j))
var json = $.parseJSON(j);
var temp = ''
$(json).each(function(i, val) {
  temp += val.id + '-' + val.name + ',';
});
console.log(temp)
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `$.each` like this:

```
......
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(json, function(i,val){ // See the change here
          $.each(val,function(k,v){
             console.log(k+" : "+ v);
          }); 
        });  
.......
```

From the Docs. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

**Edit:** Seems like this is what you want.

```
var json = $.parseJSON(j);
$.each(json,function (i, val) {
  console.log(val.id+' '+val.name)
});
```

Comment: ok buddy, it is working now, the problem is I put json in ajax response. When I removed it, now it keeps working

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax POST like this. Hope it will be helpful for you.

```
var data = "{'courseid':"+cid+"}";
    $.ajax({
        url: "updatechatusers.php",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) { },
        success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("JSOn Result======"+JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error " + jqXHR.responseText + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```